# Convert plain string to XML format

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

If I receive a string that is only a list of numbers (e.g. *1,2,3,5*), is it possible to convert it to XML format, like this?

```
<foo>
  <id>1</id>
  <id>2</id>
  <id>3</id>
</foo>
```

So far I had planned to use something along the lines of this

```
string s = "example";
XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
xm.LoadXml(string.Format("<foo>{0}</foo>", s));
```

But I'm unsure as to how I should split the string so that I only get the numbers *without* using the obvious `Split()`, which is something my manager doesn't want me to do (otherwise I'd just skip the whole XML format).

Basically, is there a way for me to 'easily' serialize that string into XML format?

Comment: What reason does your manager have for *not* wanting to use string.Split? I wouldn't suggest your XML approach, mind you... building XML by hand like that is rarely a good idea. I'd use LINQ to XML. But I'd use Split to start with...

Comment: @Jon Using Split was my first option as well, but my manager said it should be 'easier' and 'better' to use XML to manipulate the information (instead of splitting the string and turn it into a list of integers and vice versa) though I fail to see how, hence my question.

Comment: It's probably best to ask your question. Given that it's *not* XML to start with, I fail to see how adding XML into the equation makes things simpler...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LINQtoXML`

```
string items="1,4,6,3";
XElement elm = new XElement("foo");
foreach(var  item in items.Split(','))
{
    elm.Add(new XElement("id",item));
}
```

Now `ele` will have the XML you are looking for

Comment: Thank you! Although this uses Split I will mark it as the answer, is the best one I've seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XDocument.Parse(string) method

You can build up the xml string and then pass it to the method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx